# Integrating MuPDF library in Android Project

Tags: android, native-code, mupdf

I downloaded "mupdf-1.3-source" and built using Cygwin.

Which files should I import in my Android project?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to make MuPDF(currently using the 1.9 version) work with my project:

copy the jni folder in MuPDF-1.9-source into my project folder;

copy the thirdparty, generated, scripts, xps, fitz, cbz drawable folder into the jni folder that just copied over;

In res folder of my project, copy everything that the MuPDF needs, ie string values, colors, layouts, and drawables. For layout leaves the main layout alone copy the rest layouts over.

modify AndroidManifest.xml to include additional activities

I used cgywin to rebuild the libraries(?),but it gave me an error. Somehow without that step, MuPDF works for my project...